# C# XML find value of attribute in LIST - SOLVED

Tags: c#, xml

EDIT: I RESOLVED THE ISSUE, THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR ANSWERS!
Respected coders of StackOverflow I require quick assisstance,
I have xml file structured like this:

```
<kazaliste>
    <glumci>
        <glumac id="200" ime="Drasko" prezime="Zidar"></glumac>
    </glumci>
    <predstave>
        <predstava id="2120" naziv="Dubravko Habek BIJELA KUGA">
            <glumci>
                <glumac>110</glumac>
                <glumac>200</glumac>
                <glumac>170</glumac>
            </glumci>
        </predstava>
    </predstave>
    <prikazivanja>
        <prikazivanje predstava="2110" pocetak_dan="16" pocetak_mjesec="2" pocetak_godina="2020" pocetak_vrijeme="19:00"></prikazivanje>               
    </prikazivanja>
</kazaliste>
```

My structure and LIST:

```
    public struct Predstave
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Naziv;
        public List<int> gID;

        public Predstave(int id, string naziv, List<int> gid)
        {
            ID = id;
            Naziv = naziv;
            //asign gid to gID
            gID = gid;
        }
    }
```

LIST:

```
        public static void PrikaziSvePredstaveSaGlumcima()
    {
        List<Predstave> predstava = DohvatiPredstave();

        List<Glumci> glumac = DohvatiGlumce();

        for (int i = 0; i < glumac.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + ". " + glumac[i].Ime + " " + glumac[i].Prezime);
            for (int k =0; k < predstava.Count; k++)
            {
                if (glumac[i].ID.Equals(predstava[k].gID))
                Console.WriteLine("Predstave: " + predstava[k].Naziv);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works, writes out all glumac in first part of xml, but no predstava with their id is shown at all.

Final result looks like this:

1. Drasko Zidar
2. Another glumac
3. ...

And I need it to look like this:

1. Drasko Zidar
   Predstave: predstava1 (with his ID as element), predstava2... so on until there is none, after that function switches to another glumac and repeats the proces
2. glumac2
   Predstave: predstava4, predstava5...

Comment: Since you have multiple `<glumac>` nodes, instead of a single `string gID` in the `struct`, use a `List<int> gID`. Also, a class instead of a struct would be a better choice.

Comment: ah thanks, ill try that. Yeah, IT would make my life easier, this is for a class im taking and basicly im forced to use only BASIC code, I can't use classes or anything else that would make my 210line code done in 40...

Comment: Well it doesn't make sense why you can't use a class instead of a struct even if it's for learning purposes. Also, instead of doing this way, it always makes more sense to do XML serialization and deserialization to do this kind of work faster.

Comment: You should use xsd.exe along Linq to XML.

Comment: @Sach I did like you suggested but im struggeling to make it work later in LIST section, i have no idiea how to define gid to point at list in struct and its values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Miller answer, Linq to Xml is simple, but if you want to use `XmlDocument`, you could modify the code like :

1 - `sXml` for test :

```
string sXml = @"
<kazaliste>
    <predstave>
     <predstava id='2110' naziv='Vaclav Havel AUDIJENCIJA'>
      <glumci>
       <glumac>140</glumac>
       <glumac>200</glumac>
      </glumci>
     </predstava>
      <predstava id='2111' naziv='Vaclav Havel AUDIJENCIJA1'>
      <glumci>
       <glumac>141</glumac>
       <glumac>201</glumac>
      </glumci>
     </predstava>
    </predstave>
</kazaliste>";
```

2 - *Predstave* class, change the little the constructor:

```
public struct Predstave
{
    public int ID;
    public string Naziv;
    public List<int> gID;

    public Predstave(int id, string naziv, List<int> gid)
    {
        ID = id;
        Naziv = naziv;
        //asign gid to gID
        gID = gid;
    }
}
```

3 - *DohvatiPredstave* method, you could loop on *glumac* for each *predstava* node, like :

```
XmlDocument oXml = new XmlDocument();
oXml.LoadXml(sXml);

XmlNodeList oNodes = oXml.SelectNodes("//kazaliste/predstave/predstava");
foreach (XmlNode oNode in oNodes)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(oNode.Attributes["id"].Value);
    string naziv = oNode.Attributes["naziv"].Value;
    List<int> gid = new List<int>();

    foreach (XmlNode gNode in oNode.SelectNodes("./glumci/glumac"))
    {
        gid.Add(Convert.ToInt32(gNode.InnerText));
    }

    Predstave oPredstava = new Predstave(id, naziv, gid);
    predstava.Add(oPredstava);
}
```

4 - Linq to Xml `XDcoument`:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(sXml);

List<Predstave> result = xDocument.Descendants("predstava")
    .Select(x => new Predstave
    {
        ID = int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value),
        Naziv = x.Attribute("naziv").Value,
        gID = x.Descendants("glumac")
            .Select(y => int.Parse(y.Value))
            .ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: DohvatiPredstave method returns me error, Data at root level invalid. Line 1 Position 1

Comment: @D.G. for XmlDocumeent or XDocument? i have tested the xml posted by adding root `kazaliste` and it's work fine. the `sXml` is a string or filePath?

Comment: @D.G. i have add the `sXml` to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, so after a bit of tinkering I made it work, now I'm only missing one part of code i really have no idiea how to do. I updated my question with new code and a bit more of xml for better understanding

Comment: @D.G. you should post another question, multiple question in one is not authorized :) and i don't understand the expected result. you could also post the code of `DohvatiPredstave` and `DohvatiGlumce`.

Comment: I know, sorry, didn't want to clutter with this basic questions. I found a piece of code that works, i just get error CS0029 now, trying to figure that out now.

Answer (score 2):

You may use struct but better use Xml Linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleXml
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Predstave
        {
            public int ID;
            public string Naziv;
            public List<int> gID;

            public Predstave(int id, string naziv)
            {
                ID = id;
                Naziv = naziv;
                gID = new List<int>();
            }

            public override String ToString()
            {
                return "{id: " + ID + ", Naziv: " + Naziv + ", gID: [" + string.Join(", ", gID) + "]}";
            }
        }

        public static List<Predstave> DohvatiPredstave(string sXml)
        {           
            //Load xml
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(sXml);

            //Run query
            var oNodes = from oNode in xdoc.Descendants("predstava")
            select new
            {
                ID = oNode.Attribute("id").Value,
                Naziv = oNode.Attribute("naziv").Value,
                Glumci = oNode.XPathSelectElements("glumci/glumac")
            };

            List<Predstave> predstava = new List<Predstave>();
            foreach (var oNode in oNodes)
            {
                Predstave oPredstava = new Predstave(int.Parse(oNode.ID), oNode.Naziv);
                predstava.Add(oPredstava);
                foreach (var glumac in oNode.Glumci)
                    oPredstava.gID.Add(int.Parse(glumac.Value));
            }

            return predstava;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sXml = "<predstave><predstava id='2110' naziv='Vaclav Havel AUDIJENCIJA'><glumci><glumac>140</glumac><glumac>200</glumac></glumci></predstava></predstave>";
            List<Predstave> predstava = DohvatiPredstave(sXml);
            //Loop through results
            foreach (var oPredstava in predstava)
                Console.WriteLine(oPredstava);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```